# Two levels deep one-to-many relationship with contains()

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have two tables like so

```
class Department(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    employees = relationship('Employee', backref='department')

class Employee(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    department_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('department.id'))
    email_addresses = relationship('EmailAddress', backref='employee')

class EmailAddress(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String)
    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'))
```

And now I need to find all departments that have an employee with an email address of X.

Back when each employee was allowed to have only one email address (so they had `email_address = Column(String)` I used this code, but I'm not sure how to extend it to work with multiple emails:

```
session.query(Department).filter(
    Employee.email_address==request.args['email']
).outerjoin((Employee, Department.employees))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the any() method of relationship. This code should do it:

```
session.query(Department).filter(
    Employee.email_address.any(value=request.args['email'])
).outerjoin((Employee, Department.employees))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this in a few hours. Is it just `value=request.args['email']` Instead of `EmailAddress.value==request.args['email']`? This is all I found: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any

Comment: Both statements should be equivalent in your case. However, note that if you do not write EmailAddress., you have to use a single = because then it is not a condition but a parameter.

Comment: Yeah awesome thanks! I chose this answer over BrunoThomas's solution with `EmailAddress.value==request.args['email']` because it's shorter, requires no access to `EmailAdress` class (less imports) and doesn't require an additional `outerjoin`

Answer (score 1):

You could use any() like this :

```
department1 = Department()
department2 = Department()
DBSession.add(department1)
DBSession.add(department2)
employee = Employee()
employee.email_addresses.append(EmailAddress(employee.id, 'e@mail.com'))
DBSession.add(employee)
department1.employees.append(employee)
DBSession.flush() 
print(DBSession.query(Department).filter(Department.employees.any(Employee.email_addresses.any(EmailAddress.value == 'e@mail.com'))).all())
```

see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bamthomas/f1a0e03696d71847dd429ee9a75e0fde) for a full example.